# Vue.js - Toggle a method for a specific question answers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am working on a simple toggle function. It is a FAQ and if you click on the icon it should show the answer to the specific question.

The function works but every answer gets toggled, so all answers are shown on click and I only want to show the specific question.

I hope you guys can help me.

HTML

```
    <div class="faq-question">
      <p class="question">Question 1. This is question One</p>
      <font-awesome-icon @click="toggleAnswer()" :icon="['fas', 'angle-right']" class="arrow-icon" />
    </div>
    <div class="faq-answer">
      <p class="answer" v-show="togglerAnswer">{{casino[0].FAQ_Answer_One}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-question">
      <p class="question">Question 2. This is question Two</p>
      <font-awesome-icon @click="toggleAnswer()" :icon="['fas', 'angle-right']" class="arrow-icon" />
    </div>
    <div class="faq-answer">
      <p class="answer" v-show="togglerAnswer">{{casino[0].FAQ_Answer_Two}}</p>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
toggleAnswer() {
            if(!this.togglerAnswer) {
                this.togglerAnswer = true;
            } else {
                this.togglerAnswer = false;
            }
        }
```

@EDIT

```
export default {
    asyncData({ params }) {
        return axios.get(casinoURL + params.casinos).then(res => {
            return { 
                casino: res.data, 
                casinoID: res.data[0].id, 
                casinoBonus: res.data[0].bonuses,
                casinoPros: res.data[0].brand_pros,
                casinoCons: res.data[0].brand_cons,
                casinoGames: res.data[0].verticals,
                casinoTags: res.data[0].brand_tags,
                casinoAnswers: res.data[0].FAQ_Answer_One,
            };
        })
    },
    data() {
        return {
            casino: [],
            casinoID: null,
            casinoPros: [],
            casinoCons: [],
            casinoGames: [],
            casinoTags: [],
            casinoAnswers: [],
            togglerAnswer: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleAnswer() {
            if(!this.togglerAnswer) {
                this.togglerAnswer = true;
            } else {
                this.togglerAnswer = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another property called `toggledAnswerIndex` which initially set to `-1` and use it like :

```
@click="toggleAnswer(1)" // 1 for answer one 2 for answer two and so on
```

in the method :

```
toggleAnswer(index) {
            if(!this.togglerAnswer) {
                this.togglerAnswer = true;
              this.toggledAnswerIndex =index
            } else {
                this.togglerAnswer = false;
                this.toggledAnswerIndex =-1;
            }
        }
```

in template :

```
 <div class="faq-answer">
      <p class="answer" v-show="togglerAnswer && toggledAnswerIndex ===1 ">{{casino[0].FAQ_Answer_Two}}</p>
    </div>
```

**Edit**

you should return an array `casinoAnswers` in  [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data#using-asyncawait) like :

```
 async asyncData({ params }) {
    let res= await axios.get(casinoURL + params.casinos)
     return {casinoAnswers :res.data}
 
 }
```

and remove `casinoAnswers` from data option.

template :

```
 <template v-for="(cas,index) in casinoAnswers ">
 <div class="faq-question" v-for="(cas,index) in casino">
  <p class="question">Question {{index}}. This is question {{index}}</p>
  <font-awesome-icon @click="toggleAnswer(index)" :icon="['fas', 'angle-right']" class="arrow-icon" />
</div>
 <div class="faq-answer">
   <p class="answer" v-show="togglerAnswer && toggledAnswerIndex===index">{{cas.FAQ_Answer_One}}</p>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this with v-for and key attribute ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that each answer is a new String in the api call and I dont really know how to save every answer in an array :(

Comment: @foka135 how do you get that answers ? storing them in  an array will make the task easier

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I tried to store them in an Array but the array will only store the first question. I edited the question so you could see how I made the call

Comment: please share all the code, i think you did a mistake somewhere

Comment: Okay, if you need more information let me know and thank you for helping me.

Comment: you want to store the result inside the `casino` array?

Comment: I want store all of the answers in the casinoAnswers Array

Comment: I think the template should work fine but the casinoAnswers has all of the data now in it and I only need the strings FAQ_Answer_One, FAQ_Answer_Two and so on.

Comment: Isnt there a way to just store the casinoAnswers in one array?

Comment: you could use `map` method to return only the needed fields `return {casinoAnswers :res.data}.map(item=>{return{FAQ_Answer_One:item.FAQ_Answer_One,FAQ_Answer_Two:item.FAQ_Answer_Two,}}`

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked and all Answers are now stored in an array.

Comment: you're welcome, please don't forget to accept and vote up the answer